# Why my jxplorer unable to show the data needed?

Tags: authentication, ldap

I would like to get the whole data which stored in my ldap server.

I first logged in on jxplorer. After logging in, I expect to get the whole data on my jxplorer, but it just show me some field filled, not all of them:

[image: http://postimage.org/image/497y5vwy5/]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question is off topic but believe me JXplorer shows you what's there, and not there, correctly. I've been using it non-stop for 3-4 years for exactly that purpose. Possibly the server isn't allowing you access to all those attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reasons for not seeing data usually relate to permissions.

On the one hand, while you may think you are correctly authenticated perhaps instead you only succeeded at an anonymous bind, and therefore can only see publicly accessible attributes.

On the other hand, perhaps your account you did properly bind with has insufficient rights to see what you want.

On the gripping hand... Darn, I cannot think of a third one to make that joke.

Comment: i log in with the user and the password, so i think i need to ask ldap server admin for the right to see those attributes? or do i need to log in with ssl also?

Comment: @user2186299 It depends on how they are configured.  I would say, No, you do not require SSL, but the admin might have it so configured.  You will need sufficient permissions to read, so might as well ask for them.

Answer (score 1):

Use the admin account. SSL is not required.